# Git tag information - Which branch am I on?

Tags: git, github, git-tag

Git tag commands provide information about all the tags on that repository. For example, when I run `git tag` on my repository, it displays

```
tag1.0
tag1.1
tag1.2
```

Let's say my repository has two branches. How would I know which branch the `tag1.0` tag was related to?

Yes, I know that if I do `git show tag1.0`, I can tell whether this is the 1st branch or 2nd based on the previous changes. However, I'd like to know if there a more direct method exists. If it exists, what command would I need to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
git branch --contains tag1.0
```